# module 'altair' has no attribute 'Chart'?

Tags: python-3.x, module, altair

I am quite new to python coding and would like to explore the Altair librairy.
As suggested in the **Basic Statistical Visualization** section of the online guide (https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/starting.html), I tried to run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('CCCDDDEEE'),
                     'b': [2, 7, 4, 1, 2, 6, 8, 4, 7]})

chart = alt.Chart(data)
alt.Chart.mark_point().encode(data)
chart
```

IDLE output is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rodolphe/OneDrive/Rodolphe/python/altair/basics.py", line 7, in <module>
    chart = alt.Chart(data)
AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'Chart'**
```

I may be missing something obvious but I can't see it.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add information about how you installed altair? And what is the output of ``alt.__path__`` and ``alt.__file__``?

Comment: I installed altair with pip. The output of `alt.__path__` and `alt.__file__` is `AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute '__path / file'`

Comment: It looks like you are not importing the actual altair module, but rather an altair file or directory elsewhere in your Python path. Make certain there are no directories named ``altair`` or files named ``altair.py`` within your current directory, or within your python path.

Comment: Thank you @jakevdp ! It works perfectly without any `altair.py` in the directory.

Comment: OK - I added an answer with a bit more detail

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you're not importing the `altair` that you think you are.

When you execute `import altair`, Python looks for a package named `altair` or a file named `altair.py` in a specific list of directories, which by default starts with the current working directory. I suspect you have a file named `altair.py` in your working directory or in one of the directories listed in `sys.path`, so when you `import altair`, Python is importing this.

You can find out which file you're importing by running

```py
import altair
print(altair.__file__)
```

Remove or rename this file, and the import will find the altair package you've installed.